# Sort a sequence of log-data into appropriate view to the user (FIFO synonim)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Have no idea on to find this, that's why I bring my apologies in advance to the community.

I have a problem with sorting a sequence of log-data into the appropriate view to the user.

By default, all data is being logged in two ways: when inserted (operation=1) and when deleted(operation=3).

A table Logs has following columns: old, new, operation and date.
On INSERT, **old** column is NULL and **new** column gets a value. On DELETE, **old** column gets a value and **new** colum is NULL.

U can see this on the sample code

```
 ;with x as (select null old, 'A' new, 1 operation, cast('20130822 12:00:01.100' as datetime) dt
         union all 
         select null,'B', 1 , '20130822 12:00:01.700' dt
         union all
         select 'B',null, 3 , '20130822 12:00:02.100' dt
         union all
         select null,'C', 1 , '20130822 12:00:05.700' dt
         union all
         select 'C',null, 3 , '20130822 12:00:06.100' dt
         union all 
         select null,'B', 1 , '20130822 12:00:08.700' dt
         )
```

The result I need to get should look like this:

```
OLD     NEW      TIME
        A        22-08-2013 12:00:01
A|      A|B      22-08-2013 12:00:01
A|B     A|B|C    22-08-2013 12:00:02
A|B|C   A|C      22-08-2013 12:00:05
A|C     A        22-08-2013 12:00:06
A       A|B      22-08-2013 12:00:08
```

I tried to run this via *for xml path*, but still didn't get the result.
Also, no cycles are possible. I need to get one query, that is possible to join to another query.

As I see, here I need to check ranges due to operation type and time it has been applied.
May be someone have suggestions on how to deal with that? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is not easy but it works.

```
;with x(old, new, operation, dt) as (
    select null, 'A',  1, cast('20130822 12:00:01.100' as datetime) union all
    select null, 'B',  1, '20130822 12:00:01.700' dt union all
    select 'B',  null, 3, '20130822 12:00:02.100' dt union all
    select null, 'C',  1, '20130822 12:00:05.700' dt union all
    select 'C',  null, 3, '20130822 12:00:06.100' dt union all
    select null, 'B',  1, '20130822 12:00:08.700' dt
), y as (
    select x1.dt, isnull(x2.new, x2.old) u
    from x x1
    inner join x x2 on x1.dt >= x2.dt
    group by x1.dt, isnull(x2.new, x2.old)
    having sum((x2.operation - 2) * (-1)) > 0
)

select min(case i when 1 then new end) old
    , min(case i when 0 then new end) new
    , min(case i when 0 then dt end) dt
from (
    select distinct dt
        , dense_rank() over(order by dt) num
        , stuff ( (
            select '|' + u
            from y y2
            where y1.dt = y2.dt
            for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '') new
    from y y1
) t
cross join (values(0),(1))i(i)
group by num+i
having min(case i when 0 then dt end) is not null
order by dt
```

Comment: Maybe there is possible somehow to optimize this query as when I replaced the first statement *with x as()* onto my real data query (from a table with over 10 billions of records of log, joined with other many-recorded tables) - I got 21 second for execution. And when I saw IO stats - I was shocked due to 2 billions _logical reads_ on my Log and other tables. However when I dropped data to temp table (@tmp alike) - it worked normally and diligent. Somehow a *with* operator doesn't act like a @tmp table. What can be done to optimize?

Comment: Oh, and there is a problem with getting **operation** field back to the query at the end...

Comment: For getting **operation** field just add `x1.operation` into _y_ cte in _select_ and _group by_ parts. Then add this field to final query: `select distinct dt, operation` and `min(case i when 0 then operation end) operation`

Comment: Thanks! But what do you think about the plans I've mentioned? Can I avoid using tmp table?

Comment: Can you explain also what algorythm did you choose to solve this situation? Why there is a need to duplicate values with sequence Value-Null?

Comment: If you are talking about final query logic is as follows: I noticed that Old value equals New value of previous row. So final query gets previous value for each row. Maybe you even don't need this. =)

Comment: To improve performance of the query you may create indexes on appropriate columns or you may filter input data (what do you need all the 10 billions records for?)